# Rails deployment with capistrano and bundler

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, capistrano, bundle

I want to deploy an rails app on a server, where the following setup is given.

Systemwide installed is ruby and rubygems.
As user i installed bundler and added the ~/.gems/bin to the path.

inside the Capfile i set bundle_cmd to the local installation like

```
set :bundle_cmd, "/home/user/.gems/bin/bundle"
```

calling "bundle" from the cap shell is giving me the following error

```
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:779:in `report_activate_error': Could not find RubyGem bundler (>= 0) (Gem::LoadError)
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:214:in `activate'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:1082:in `gem'
/home/user/.gems/bin/bundle:18
```

Any ideas?

Okay, i could install bundler as root but is that possible without?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the cap shell doesnt get your settings from the bashrc like GEM_HOME or the path of bundler.

I tried it before with

```
source .bashrc && bundle
```

but that didnt do the trick for me.

```
set :bundle_cmd, "export GEM_HOME=/home/user/.gems;export PATH=$PATH:/home/user/.gems/bin && bundle"
```

does work though.